# Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript

I cannot display all the results because on the following channel there is no image and therefore I have the following message

```
$.get('https://wcf.tourinsoft.com/Syndication/3.0/cdt33/c616ab2a-1083-4ba0-b8e2-f7741e443e46/Objects?$format=json', function(data) {
  //$.get('/json/ecranv2.json', function(data){

  var blogs = data.value;

  $(blogs).each(function() {
    var manifs = this.Listingraisonsociale;
    var ouverturecomp = this.Listinginformationsouverture;
    var commune = this.Listingcommune;
    var ouverture = this.Listingouverture;
    var photos = this.Listingphotos;


    //var datatest= this.Listingphotos;
    let output = '';

    let users = this.Listingphotos.split('$');
    //var testsplit = split($);

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      console.log(users[i]);
      output += '<img src=' + users[i] + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1>';
    }
    $('.target').append('<p>' + manifs + '</p><span>' + output + '</span>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please include sufficient details to make your issue clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: SO `Listingphotos` is null

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. `$(blogs).each(function(){` looks like jQuery code. If so, though, it seems unlikely to be what you meant, given that `blogs` looks like some kind of data structure. You may have meant `$.each(blogs)`. But we can't really tell from the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The one index does not have a value for the property. It is null, so you need to check to see if it is null before you try to use split on it. A simple truthy check will work in this case.

```
let users = this.Listingphotos ?  this.Listingphotos.split('$') : [];
```

With it in place:

```js
$.get('https://wcf.tourinsoft.com/Syndication/3.0/cdt33/c616ab2a-1083-4ba0-b8e2-f7741e443e46/Objects?$format=json', function(data) {
  //$.get('/json/ecranv2.json', function(data){

  var blogs = data.value;

  $(blogs).each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    var manifs = this.Listingraisonsociale;
    var ouverturecomp = this.Listinginformationsouverture;
    var commune = this.Listingcommune;
    var ouverture = this.Listingouverture;
    var photos = this.Listingphotos;


    //var datatest= this.Listingphotos;
    let output = '';

    let users = this.Listingphotos ?  this.Listingphotos.split('$') : [];
    //var testsplit = split($);

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      console.log(users[i]);
      output += '<img src=' + users[i] + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1>';
    }
    $('.target').append('<p>' + manifs + '</p><span>' + output + '</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` is a method on string objects, which will be called on an actual string's reference.

So in your case, the split is not being called on a string, and the error message clearly states that we are using split over a null object. So make sure the object you are working on is an actual string, and work on it accordingly.

[split mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)